# Azure Cloud Service Deployment Error

Tags: azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I trying to Deploy a moderated size project in cloud as Service,

it giving me a fatal error , i am not able to figure out what the mean of error and cause is

**Azure Deployment Stack Trace** :

```
Role instances recycled for a certain amount of times during an update or upgrade operation.
This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided
when configuring the service prevent role instances from running. 
The most likely reason for this is that your code throws an unhandled exception.
Please consider fixing your service or changing your configuration settings so that 
role instances do not throw unhandled exceptions. 
Then start another update or upgrade operation. Until you start another update or upgrade 
operation, Windows Azure will continue trying to update your service to the new version or 
configuration you provided
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of deployment error, you better try to run your application first in the Azure Compute Emulator and then deploy in the Cloud. So you can get the unhandled exception information, also don't forget have try catch in your code.